# Getting max messages in spark DStream batches when the messages in Kafka queues are not distributed equally

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am setting the spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition : 100. It is working fine in normal condition. The problem comes when the msgs are not equally distributed in Kafka queues. What is happening is even though there are no msgs in a partitions and whereas other partition has more messages (more than maxRatePerPartition), the spark Dstream batch is getting created with less number of messages.

> The messages in the batch is comes down (less than batchsize * maxRatePerPartition * duration) when there is no equal distribution of msgs in kafka queues

As we know, in real time the unequal distribution of msgs in kafka queues is common. How to solve the problem. I want the number of msgs in every batch should be maximum.

Comment: Do you have control over the producer of those messages?

Answer (score 0):

> As we know, in real time the unequal distribution of msgs in kafka
> queues is common

Distribution of messages in Kafka topics depends on the partitioning logic at the producer side and has nothing to do with *real-time* or otherwise.

If you feel that you have uneven distribution of messages, you should change your partitioning logic accordingly using a custom [partitioner](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html)

From consumer side, you might want to try increasing

```
# Default: 500 (in Confluent Platform)
max.poll.records

# Default: 1 MB
max.partition.fetch.bytes (partition level)

# Default: 50 MB
fetch.max.bytes (total fetch request level)
```

Additionally, you might also want to checkout broker and topic level limitations for those sizes and adjust accordingly.

```
# Broker config
message.max.bytes

# Topic config
max.message.bytes
```

Comment: what i am looking is when there is no msg in a partition then the msgs in other partition should get the chance earlier. Not necessary to wait for next or future batch, Why because Spark can the resource allocated to process the max.

Comment: Dstream gets latest offsets in each topic+partition, and accordingly defines the offset ranges to process in each batch. Did you check `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` ?